# Já existe uma linguagem estruturada para processadores quânticos?

Tags: independente-de-linguagem, programação-estruturada

Os processadores quânticos estão em um largo processo de desenvolvimento há muitos anos. Contudo, nós, "meros mortais", ainda não possuímos acesso em larga escala a esses equipamentos poderosos (algo semelhante ao que acontecia com os computadores antes da era dos computadores pessoais, como o IBM PC).

A minha dúvida, basicamente, é em qual estágio de desenvolvimento estamos. Já temos uma linguagem de programação estruturada, como o `C` e o `Pascal`, ou ainda estamos longe disso, como `Assembly` ou até anterior a este?

Comment: [Q#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/language/?view=qsharp-preview)

Comment: **Algumas respostas:** [What programming languages are available for quantum computers?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1474) - PS: se alguém for importar aqui para o site recomendo que leia um a um dos links e não apenas uma tradução, porque em 1 ano (+ou- tempo das resposta) algo pode ter mudado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe uma linguagem de programação para algoritmos quânticos que foi criada pela Microsoft, o nome dela é [Q#](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/development-kit), não cheguei a utilizar mas pelo que vi o QDK (O kit de desenvolvimento) consegue rodar tanto encima de python quanto de C#.